# Setting my property variable based on what my api is returning and populating the one that are dynamically created

Tags: c#

I have the following scenario.   My ultimate goal is to return my "trackingId" if I have (serviceResults.Status == ServiceStatus.Success). First I'm getting a pending status and my loop will work correctly then it keep looping until I get a success status and my variable are not set correctly.

My only issue is visual studio does not recognize this property on the first call serviceResults.partnerReference.trackingID . I'm trying to come with a better logic. Any help will be appreciated...

```
        var finished = false;
        var trackingId = ""

        do {
           var serviceResults = await client.Services.GetServiceOrderStatusAsync..... 
            
           //This is correct
           if (serviceResults.Status == ServiceStatus.Pending) {
               finished = false;
           }
           // This is not correct because this serviceResults.partnerReference.trackingID was never 
           //initialized on the first call.
           if (serviceResults.Status == ServiceStatus.Success) {
               trackingId = serviceResults.partnerReference.trackingID  -> this never exist
               finished = true;
           }
              }
       while (!finished);
```

Here is my two postman call:
Pending
[image]

then success
[image]

Maybe one of my solutions was this??

```
      if (serviceResults.Status == ServiceStatus.Success) {
                
                dynamic serviceResulys = await 
                client.Services.GetServiceOrderStatusAsync("11158174", transactionId).ConfigureAwait(false);
                trackingId = serviceResulys.serviceResults.trackingID;
                finished = true;
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep waiting until you get the result you could simply run while loop infinite times, once you get the results you can break the loop something like below rather introducing so many variables for controlling the looping process.

```
  while (true)
        { 
            var serviceResults = await client.Services.GetServiceOrderStatusAsync.....
                 
            if (serviceResults.Status == ServiceStatus.Success)
            {
                trackingId = serviceResults.partnerReference.trackingID;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: yes the while loop can work but my reference: trackingId = serviceResults.partnerReference.trackingID; is incorrect..

Comment: serviceResults is it strongly typed or json object? you could try converting to dynamic object? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic  `dynamic serviceResults = await client.Services.GetServiceOrderStatusAsync`